# Is there a delay when using the Box.com search API?

Tags: search, box-api

I'm using the Search API as defined here:

https://developers.box.com/docs/#search

It works well, though I noticed that when I make a folder on the site, then immediately call the API searching for that folder name, it doesn't appear in the results for a minute or so. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or some way to force it to do a live search? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. It just takes a little bit of time for the search indexes to be updated with the new file/folder metadata. There's nothing you can do client-side to speed this up.

If you need immediate access that new folder, consider saving the folder `ID` that's returned in the response of the [Create a New Folder](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-create-a-new-folder) request.

Comment: Aren't you planning to change this? This makes search API pretty unusable for me right now. What if I have to find the file in another request in which I do not know its parent ID? Only solution which I see is to store BOX items IDs in my DB...